# Power BI not recognizing a number in formula, but will recognize 0

Tags: powerbi, average

I've created a formula to return an average of the origin count when the SF% is above 2. However, PowerBI is not returning the answer I'm looking for.

SF% is a new measure I created from two columns in the data table.

```
DAX : Avg. above 2% SF = IF([SF%]>2,(AVERAGEX(VALUES('Grid Data'[Origin]),[Total Origin])))
```

If I put in a 0 for the 2 it returns a value, but with the 2 it just returns a (Blank).

I've tried using Calculate(Average(Filter(... and I get the error of I cannot use a filter within the calculate.

I've tried another format and it comes back and says that it cannot work with a string.

```
Avg. above 2% SF = IF([SF%]>2,(AVERAGEX(VALUES('Grid Data'[Origin]),[Total Origin])))

Avg. 2% or Above = CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Grid Data'[Origin]), [SF%]>2)
```

I would like to see an average of the origin when SF% is above 2%.

Right now it is returning (Blank) with the 2 in the formula, but when I insert a 0 for the 2 it returns an answer.

Comment: Are you keeping in mind that 2% = .02?  I don't know what your data looks like, but seeing that constant number 2 makes me suspicious.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried .02 and it keeps returning the same output. I'm going to make a new table with the values laid out and go from there. It seems like an easier option than trying to wrangle the formula.I think it is seeing it as a total value and not a per day value, so everything above the 0 is being counted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that it's computing the average once rather than for each `Origin` values in your first formula. I think you want something more like this:

```
Avg. 2% or Above =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE( 'Grid Data'[Origin] ),
    FILTER( 'Grid Data', [SF%] > 0.02 )
)
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but it is telling me that the function AVERAGE cannot work with value type of String.

Comment: Oh. Origin is a string? How do you "average" a string?